# Devanagari text not shown in 2007 ipod Classic 160 gb

Tags: itunes, ipod, ipod-classic

I have a 2007 iPod Classic (160 gb). I added songs from my pc (using iTunes) to my iPod. The songs have id3 tags and lyrics. But when I play the songs on my iPod and try to see the lyrics only English lyrics are shown. When I try to see lyrics of Hindi songs the Devanagari text is not shown and the lyrics page is blank. The same is true for the song titles. The Hindi lyrics can be seen under the song info in iTunes. Is there a software or app which can be added to the iPod to allow it to show Devanagari text?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There’s no way to do what you want as far as I know.  The iPod classic never supported Hindi or any other complex script, and there is no way to add anything. See the tech specs

https://support.apple.com/kb/sp572?locale=en_US

Comment: That is so sad. I really hoped that something would come up. :(.    Thanks,